# how to extract array indices using regular expressions in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a range string either in the form of [Numeric1] or [Numeric1:Numeric2]
Brackets are part of string as well.

I want to have one regular expression that will give me Start index and another regular expression to give me End Index regardless of the input string.

I have managed to do it, but I was just wondering if there are better ways of doing it.
Here is how I did it

```
#[5]
set range_1 "\[5\]"
#[7:9]
set range_2 "\[7:9\]"

set reg_exp_for_start_index {\[([0-9]*)\]|\[([0-9]*):[0-9]*\]}
set reg_exp_for_end_index   {\[([0-9]*)\]|\[[0-9]*:([0-9]*)\]}

set iStart1 [regsub $reg_exp_for_start_index $range_1 {\1\2}]
puts "Start index for Range 1: $iStart1"

set iEnd1 [regsub $reg_exp_for_end_index $range_1 {\1\2}]
puts "End index for Range 1: $iEnd1"

set iStart2 [regsub $reg_exp_for_start_index $range_2 {\1\2}]
puts "Start index for Range 2: $iStart2"

set iEnd2 [regsub $reg_exp_for_end_index $range_2 {\1\2}]
puts "End index for Range 2: $iEnd2"
```

I get the expected output which is

```
Start index for Range 1: 5
End index for Range 1: 5
Start index for Range 2: 7
End index for Range 2: 9
```

What I don't like is I used or (|)
and I have to concatenate the strings as  {\1\2}.

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexp` instead.

```
set range {[5]}
regexp -- {\[([0-9]*)(?::([0-9]*))?\]} $range -> start end
puts "Range: $range"
puts "Start: $start"
puts "End:   $end"
```

Also, you probably don't want numbers in formats like `007` as ranges, or empty strings either.

```
regexp -- {\[([1-9]\d*)(?::([1-9]\d*))?\]} $range -> start end
```

Here's [an Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/coB3AK).

Finally, the `--` simply ends switches. It's a habit of mine. And the `->` is only an aesthetic trick, relying on the fact that `->` is a valid identifier in Tcl. It could just as well be:

```
regexp -- {\[([1-9]\d*)(?::([1-9]\d*))?\]} $range match start end
```

Comment: Also, `regexp` returns whether it found a match, so you can do `if {[regexp ...]} { ... }`.

Comment: why is "007" an invalid number?

Comment: @glennjackman - Rephrased to "numbers in formats like `007`". Obviously there's no grounds by which to say it's invalid. It just seems weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set reg_exp_for_start_index {\[([0-9]*)(?::[0-9]*)?\]}
set reg_exp_for_end_index   {\[(?:[0-9]*:)?([0-9]*)\]}
```

That way you only have one capture group for each regex.